# How are user's timezone encoded in facebook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I need to check user's time zone... but I can't find how it defined really.
[The reference API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) says : *The user's timezone offset from UTC*

Now on Wikipedia these are the [timezone possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#Time_zone_as_offsets_from_UTC).
Take India as an example :  UTC+05:30.

So **how does facebook encode** this in users's field **timezone**.
Since I'm in Europe my own timezone is : 2, actually it should be 1 but I presume the summer time is build in. Howerver I don't know for sure.

Comment: The document you link to tells you that it is a number, so I expect 1 or -1 as an example. It also says it is available only for the current user, so is probably not accessable by apps.

Comment: @vascowhite and what about 5:30 for India ? Well my app requires offline_access to work, and also in case I could always store it.

Comment: Do you think it could be +5.5?

Comment: @vascowhite or may be FB does not have this half time zone. Do I have to parse the input as a floating point number ?

Comment: Why not try it and see what happens? I have no idea what you want to do with the number, so it's hard to answer that.

Comment: @vascowhite I want check if the user is in a specific TZ, to test I need to change TZ.

Comment: Surely you can figure that out!

Comment: See also my answer to @Adam, basically you are right the answer is `5.5`

Comment: How did you convert 5.5 to 5:30 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the graph explorer with a valid token (or request a token) and look at an example. You'll see that the timezone is a number representing the hours ahead or behind UTC.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me

Mine is currently 1, which is BST (UTC + 1 hour). I believe yours, being in France, will be 2 (summertime is automatic), and San Francisco will be -7. India will be 5.5

Comment: how about India which is supposed to be +5:30 ? As the question mentionned.

Comment: It'll be 5:30. You can always change your computer timezone, log out of facebook and back in and try the opengraph tool linked in my answer.

Comment: of course I did not think of changing my own TZ and test. I'll let you know.

Comment: TZ is a FB data which does not change with changing your computer TZ. Just tried and it failed. So I don't even know how to test.

Comment: According to this Facebook FAQ answer, that's exactly how it's changed - https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=220393734657140

Comment: actually you can NOT change your account TZaccording to [this page](https://fr-fr.facebook.com/help/?faq=17276&hloc=en_US). It captures the TZ when you create your account. So you need 1. to change your computer TZ & 2. create a new account.

Comment: if you update your answer with the 5.5, I'll tick your answer too. Thx.